# OOP javascript trying to access a method

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I have writeen the ETF class. which is an attempt to write in OOP in javascript.

The class is called ETF. and the methods are getData and draw.
I am trying to access method 'draw' from method 'getData'

```
function ETF(){
    //global variable


}
//class methods => getData (from xml file), draw(draws the bar )
ETF.prototype ={
    getData: function(is_load, DateDiff){

        $.getJSON(
            "server/ETF.server.php",{
                mycase: 1
            },
            function(data){
                lng_pr  = data.longs_prec;
                sh_pr   = data.shorts_prec;
                ETF.draw(lng_pr, sh_pr); // <== how to access the draw method?
        });

    },//end getData
    //draw the 
    draw: function(lng_pr, sh_pr){
         //draw code..
        }
```

tried 'this.draw' but nothing..

anyone?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the `ETF` class, what the `draw` method is supposed to do, and what error you are encountering.

Comment: How in the world do you expect anybody to understand what you're trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to access method 'draw' from method 'getData'

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign "this" to a variable so you can access it within $.getJSON.  If you tried to call the method using this.draw(lng_pr, sh_pr), "this" would be referring to the context of $.getJSON, not your current ETF object.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
function ETF(){
    //global variable


}
//class methods => getData (from xml file), draw(draws the bar )
ETF.prototype ={
    getData: function(is_load, DateDiff){
        var obj = this;  //assign current ETF object to a variable

        $.getJSON(
            "server/ETF.server.php",{
                mycase: 1
            },
            function(data){
                lng_pr  = data.longs_prec;
                sh_pr   = data.shorts_prec;
                obj.draw(lng_pr, sh_pr);  //will call your draw method below
        });

    },//end getData
    //draw the 
    draw: function(lng_pr, sh_pr){
         //draw code..
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you write the "class" like this:?

```
function ETF() {
    var that = this,
        /* holds the public methods / properties */
        thisObject = {};


    thisObject.getData = function(is_load, DateDiff){

        $.getJSON(
            "server/ETF.server.php",{
                mycase: 1
            },
            function(data){
                lng_pr  = data.longs_prec;
                sh_pr   = data.shorts_prec;
                thisObject.draw(lng_pr, sh_pr); // <== how to access the draw method?
        });

    };// end getData

    thisObject.draw = function(lng_pr, sh_pr){
         //draw code..
    };

    return thisObject;
}

var etfObject = new ETF();
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the class's methods will be recreated for every instance of the class.  If you use the prototype pattern as the OP posted, this won't happen, you'll only get one set of methods that all of the objects will refer to.  Though IMO shouldn't be a down-vote as your answer will work and the extra memory it takes is not really a big deal.

Comment: @JoshNoe fair enough. Thanks for the explanation. Learned something new today.